# “If you'll come this way, Ms___ will see you now”

Tags: clauses, auxiliary-verbs

In some situations **if** can be followed by *will*, *would* or *going to* in the same clause.

> If **you'll** come this way, Ms Taylor **will** see you now.

When I used the example above, my English teacher at school told me that I was wrong and we can never use *if* followed by *will*

Can I have further explanations on this matter? Can an English conditional sentence have two clauses with "will"?

Comment: It can also be followed by many other verbs and predicates. Why are these three special? And what would you expect an answer to this question to look like?

Comment: This might be a part-duplicate of [... consider 'would' to be a polite form of 'will'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222166/which-dialects-of-english-consider-would-to-be-a-polite-form-of-will). I can't tell.

Comment: When I used the example above, my english teacher at school told me that I was wrong and we can never use if followed by will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is probably thinking of the so-called conditional 1 (first conditional) sentences in which *will* appears only in the main clause. Example:

> If you help me, I'll help you.

But your sentence is not a typical conditional. It does not mean:

> Ms Taylor will see you now, on condition that you come this way.

It means:

> Ms Taylor is ready to see you now. Please come this way.

"*If you will come this way*" is simply a polite way of saying "*Follow me!*"

You can read about different ways of expressing requests politely on the *[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/functions/politeness)* website. It includes this extract:

> In speaking, we often use if followed by *will, would, can* or *could* to introduce a polite request:
>
> - If we can move on to the next point for discussion. (more polite than Can we move on …)
> - If I could just say one more thing … (more polite than Listen to me, I want to say something.)
> - If you will follow me, please. (more polite than Follow me, please.)